# If the testbench and test are top-modules how to pass the instance of the interface within the testbench to the test

Tags: system-verilog, test-bench

I prefer to write testbench and tests as top-level modules so I can compile all of them and elaborate/optimize the testbench and test that I need to run. However, I am not sure how I can pass the instance of the interface in the testbench to the test. In the example below dut_tb is the top-level testbech and dut_tb_intf is the interface instantiated in the testbench. The test dut_tb_test uses functions in the interface that I can reference using the complete path but was wondering if I could pass the interface instance in dut_tb to the test or a better way to do this.

Please see the example below.

```
module dut(input data, input clk, input rst_n, output logic inv_data);
  logic inv_data_d;
  assign inv_data_d = ~data;

  always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
      if (~rst_n)
        inv_data <= '0;
      else
        inv_data <= inv_data_d;
endmodule

package dut_tb_pkg;
logic clk;
logic rst_n;
logic data;
logic inv_data;
endpackage

module dut_tb();

  import dut_tb_pkg::*;

  dut_tb_intf dut_tb_intf();

  //logic data;
  //logic inv_data;

  assign data = dut_tb_intf.data_i;
  assign dut_tb_intf.data_inv = inv_data;
  assign clk = dut_tb_intf.aclk;

  initial
    begin
       rst_n = '0;
       @(posedge clk);
       rst_n = '1;
    end

  dut dut (.clk (clk), .rst_n(rst_n), .data (data), .inv_data(inv_data));

endmodule

//module dut_tb_test( dut_tb.dut_tb_intf intf_inst); // DOES NOT WORK**
module dut_tb_test();

  import dut_tb_pkg::*;

  logic in, out;

  initial 
    begin
    @(posedge clk);
     #30;
    @(posedge clk);
     in = 1'b0;
     dut_tb.dut_tb_intf.inv_data (in, out);

     //intf_inst.inv_data (in, out); // DOES NOT WORK**

   end  
  initial 
    begin
    @(posedge clk);
    @(posedge clk);
     $display ("INFO_0: in is %b and out is %b\n", in, out);
     #300;
     $display ("INFO_1: in is %b and out is %b\n", in, out);
     #100;
     $finish;
    end

endmodule

interface dut_tb_intf; 

logic aclk; 
logic data_i;
logic data_inv;

   initial
     begin
        aclk = '0;
        forever #5 aclk = ~aclk;
     end

task inv_data(input i, output logic d);

 data_i = i;;
 @(posedge aclk);
 @(posedge aclk);
 d = data_inv;

endtask

modport utils (import inv_data);

endinterface
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach you can **not** pass interface between two modules. Interfaces are passed to modules through instantiation ports. In classical verilog approach you need to have yet another `top` module to instantiate all of it:

```
module tb(MyInterface i);
...
endmodule 

module test(MyInteface i);
...
endmodule

interface MyInterface;
...
endinterface

module top();
   MyInterface myIntf;
   tb tb(myIntf);
   test test(myIntf);
endmodule
```

It is possible to go a bit ugly and instantiate your interface inside tb and pass it to the test as the following

```
module top();
    tb tb();
    test test (tb.myIntf);
endmodule
```

The other approach is to instantiate your test within the testbench. This will save you all the above trouble and you can naturally pass the interface to it:

```
module test...

module tb();
   MyInterface myIf;
   test test(myIf);
   ...
endmodule
```

Or even better, in system verilog you can design your test as a class and pass *virtual interfaces* around.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to avoid having another top-level encapsulation. I had not thought about designing the test as a class - will look into it. So I suppose you mean each instance of the test can get the virtual interface and any test specific customization will occur outside the class. If there is a an example you can point me to it would be great. Thanks